# Proper structure for a join table in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rewriting a PHP based support ticket system in Rails and have run into a snag.
I have my users table created and my tickets table created

```
create_table "tickets", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",       :null => false
  t.integer  "department_id", :null => false
  t.integer  "upload_id",     :null => false
  t.string   "subject",       :null => false
  t.text     "body",          :null => false
  t.string   "status_id",     :null => false
  t.text     "url",           :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "fName",      :null => false
  t.string   "lName",      :null => false
  t.string   "seKey",      :null => false
  t.boolean  "isAdmin"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.string   "auth_token"
end
```

Everything is working great, I am able to create tickets, etc...
Now I am needing to assign 1 or more admins to a ticket and am not sure if I should use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship or a has_many :through relationship.

The way it is currently setup in PHP is just using a join table that matches a userID with a ticketID. I don't think I will ever need any other data relating to the relationship other than that so is has_and_belongs_to_many the best option?

Also, will this cause an issue since the ticket is already associated with a record in the user table (the original creator)? Basically a ticket will have multiple connections to the users table, one will be the person who submitted it and the rest are users who are assigned to handle it.

Comment: In learning Rails associations, this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) helped me out a lot, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work; however, personally, I prefer a has_many :through relationship.  The reason being is you have access to the join table.  To do this generate a model called `ticket_user` with a field called `user_id` and `ticket_id`.  Then in the model add

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :ticket
```

then you can add to the ticket model

```
has_many :ticket_users
has_many :users :through ticket_user
```

and this to the user model

```
has_many :ticket_users
has_many :ticket :through ticket_user
```

Then to retrieve all of a users tickets do

```
user.tickets
```

To get all of a tickets users do

```
ticket.users
```

For more info check out this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: If you are making the join model a model in its own right I like to try and find a more expressive name than ticket_users (maybe something like ticket_assignments).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Right now I access the creator of a ticket to get their name in the following way ticket.user.lName How would I access the users assigned?

Comment: ticket.users returns a array.  This means you can do 

ticket.users.each do |user|
    puts user.lName
end
that will log the users name

you can also do something like ticket.users.first.lName or ticket.users[3].lName

Answer (score 0):

In your case has_and_belongs_to_many is the extra relationship.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :members, :class_name => "User", :join_table => "members_tickets"
```

You can have to create one table members_users with ticket_id and member_id as fields as shown in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

now you can get list of assigned members like below

```
@ticket.members # list of members
@ticket.members << @user # add new member
```

Comment: Will this have any effect on my current model where I have has_many :tickets for my user and belongs_to :user for my ticket? Will I need to keep these relationships in the model for the original creator of the ticket or remove them when I add the has_and_belongs_to_many?

Comment: 1. create table 'tickets_users' as show
2. change to has_many :tickets to has_and_belongs_to_many
3. migrate data from tickets to 'tickets_users'
4. remove user_id from tickets

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is if I do this then how do I determine what user originally created the ticket and what users are assigned to it? The user_id in tickets currently gives the creator of the ticket.

Comment: While this answer works, it is considered better practice to use has_many :through instead.  I recommend updating this answer to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

this may work - create two relationships between user and ticket, ticket belongs_to creator, :class_name user and ticket has_many assigned_users, class_name user and in user model has_many created_tickets and has_many assigned_tickets